# I have to make telerik Grid editable on the Page Load. How do I do it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have added AllowMultiRowEdit="true" in the aspx page and have added the below code in the code behind:

```
protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        foreach (GridItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
        {
            if (item is GridEditableItem)
            {
                GridEditableItem editableItem = item as GridDataItem;
                editableItem.Edit = true;
            }
        }
        RadGrid1.Rebind();
    }
}
```

The grid is editable on the page load, but when I am editing rows and saving it,it is not getting saved.
Can you please suggest me with some answers?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not able to save the data after editing.Please help me with this

Comment: Did you bind your gridview to a database ?

Comment: Yes, I am binding gridview to db.